# How to load texture from file with transparent background in DirectX

Tags: c++, c, directx, direct3d, directx-9

Recently I've picked up a book and started to learn game programming with Direct3D and DirectX. It's been pretty good so far, but the problem is I can't get to load texture from file to backbuffer with transparent background color.

Here source code for initialize Direct3D

```
BOOL Init_Direct3D(HWND hWnd,int width,int height,BOOL fullscreen)
{
    // initialize Direct3D object
    d3d = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);
    if(d3d==NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Fail to initialize Direct3D object"),TEXT("Error"),MB_ICONERROR);
        return FALSE;
    }

    // initialize Direct3D presentation parameter
    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
    ZeroMemory(&d3dpp,sizeof(d3dpp));

    d3dpp.Windowed = !fullscreen;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_COPY;
    d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8;
    d3dpp.BackBufferCount = 1;
    d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = width;
    d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = height;
    d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = hWnd;
    d3dpp.EnableAutoDepthStencil = TRUE;
    d3dpp.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D16;
    d3dpp.PresentationInterval = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_IMMEDIATE;

    d3d->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,hWnd,D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,&d3dpp,&d3ddev);
    if(d3ddev == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Fail to initialize Direct3D device"),TEXT("Error"),MB_ICONERROR);
        return FALSE;
    }

    d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHABLENDENABLE,TRUE);
    d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_BLENDOP, D3DBLENDOP_ADD);
    d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SRCBLEND, D3DBLEND_SRCALPHA);
    d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_DESTBLEND, D3DBLEND_INVSRCALPHA);

    // get Direct3D backbuffer
    d3ddev->GetBackBuffer(0,NULL,D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO,&backbuffer);
    if(backbuffer == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("Fail to get Direct3D backbuffer"),TEXT("Error"),MB_ICONERROR);
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

And here the code for loading texture

```
LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 LoadTexture(char *filename,D3DCOLOR transcolor)
{
    LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 texture = NULL;
    D3DXIMAGE_INFO texture_info;
    HRESULT result;

    // get image info
    result = D3DXGetImageInfoFromFile(filename,&texture_info);
    if(result != D3D_OK)
        return NULL;

    // create texture
    result = D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx(d3ddev,filename,texture_info.Width,texture_info.Height,1,D3DPOOL_DEFAULT,D3DFMT_UNKNOWN,
                                    D3DPOOL_DEFAULT,D3DX_DEFAULT,D3DX_DEFAULT,transcolor,NULL,NULL,&texture);
    if(result != D3D_OK)
        return NULL;

    return texture;
}
```

And this is how I render the screen

```
// start render
if(d3ddev->BeginScene())
{
    d3ddev->StretchRect(back,NULL,backbuffer,NULL,D3DTEXF_NONE);

    sprite_handler->Begin(D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND);

    D3DXVECTOR3 position((float)doki.x,(float)doki.y,0.0f);

    sprite_handler->Draw(doki_img,&rect,NULL,&position,D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255,255,255));

    sprite_handler->End();

    d3ddev->EndScene();
}

d3ddev->Present(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What is the value of your `ColorKey`? Is it the same as the color value of the texture you want not to be drawn? Maybe posting more code would be helpful.

Comment: I use XRGB(255,0,255) as my colorkey.

Comment: where is your code to set the texture?

Comment: @Norin - Ok. Show us some more code, so we can help you.

Comment: You mean this one: doki_img = LoadTexture("test.png",D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255,0,255));

Comment: @ludesign - which part do you want?

Comment: @Norin - The call to LoadTexture() and &rect initialization. Is your png saved with transparency? If so, you could load it with `D3DXCreateTextureFromFile()` and `D3DCOLOR_RGBA()`; kick away the ColorKey.

Comment: @ludesign - My png isn't save with transparency.

Comment: @Norin - Can you attach a screenshot from your rendered texture? One thing you may try is to add the calls to `d3ddev->SetRenderState();` between `sprite_handler->Begin()` and `sprite_handler->Draw()`. I am running out of ideas. You can upload the code to a pastie and give the url (complete code and the sprite image).

Comment: @ludesign - Can I email you the complete source code?

Comment: @Norin - Sure. Go ahead.

Comment: @ludesign - Can you tell me your email address? And thank for the help.

Comment: @Norin - Send it to this address, do not forget to send me the png file too: me@vasilstoychev.com

Comment: Only a guess, could you try `D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8` as format while loading?